# Linux, How to wait some seconds before run the c code in GDB

Tags: c, linux, terminal, gdb, arguments

I am using the following command to load the c file program and run it in GDB from terminal in one click:

```
gdb --eval-command='file c.out' --eval-command='c'
```

I want to sleep some seconds after loading the program but before starting the program in GDB, some thing like:

```
gdb --eval-command='file c.out' --eval-command='<sleep 5>' --eval-command='c'
```

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: Because I got error in some time when I run the code direct after loading.

Comment: Try `--eval-command="shell sleep 5"`. What error do you get if you don't sleep? Are you attaching to a running process? If so, can you show us the full command line?

Comment: Mark Plotnick, Thanks, your solution work fine, please rewrite it as answer to accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to give gdb a command-line option that will make it pause for 5 seconds is to tell it to run the "sleep 5" command in a shell:

```
--eval-command="shell sleep 5"
```